# How to turn HTML into Markdown with Python with support for footnotes?

Tags: python, html, python-2.7, markdown, multimarkdown

I'm using [Aaron Swartz's HTML2Text.py](http://aaronsw.com/2002/html2text/) script to turn HTML into Markdown on my web app. However, it doesn't support footnotes (the `<sup>` tag is being removed). I want to make it functional with support for footnotes but I can't figure out what to do.

I tried this code, but it doesn't seem to work (I added `self.sup = 0` at the start of the script):

```
 if tag == "sup":
        if start:
            self.p(); self.o('[^] ', 0, 1); self.start = 1
            self.sup += 1
        else:
            self.sup -= 1
            self.p()
```

and also just:

```
if tag == "sup":
    self.sup()
```

The issue is that the `<sup>` tags are being removed entirely, `<li>` tags lose their id and `<a>` tags lose their rel so I get non working links.

Can anyone help me add support for the `<sup>` tag and footnotes in this script?

The script is available [here](http://pastebin.com/4kyXpF2a) (It's too long to post here). I'm using Python 2.7.9.

Thanks :)

**UPDATE:** with this code:

```
        if tag == "sup" and start:
        if has_key(attrs, 'id'):
            id = attrs.get('id', '').replace("fnref:", "")
            self.o("[^" + escape_md(id) + "]")
```

It renders the `<sup>` but it doesn't include the `<a>` inside or connects it to the `<li>` at the bottom with the actual footnote.

Comment: Did you try anything yet or are you asking for anyone to code for you? ;-)

Comment: @ddh I have tried adding `if tag == "sup": self.sup = 0` or `if tag == "sup":
            if start:
                self.p(); self.o('[^] ', 0, 1); self.start = 1
                self.sup += 1
            else:
                self.sup -= 1
                self.p()`  and other statements involving `if tag == "sup"` but I can't manage to succeed so I'm looking for help finding what to use. I'll add those to the question. Sorry for not knowing, new here :)

Comment: @dhh I edited the question now with a more detailed information of what I need and what I tried, also look at my other comment, I accidently misspelled your name (sorry!) so you didn't see it.